# Type X is part of the declarations of 2 modules (Angular 2 RC5)

Tags: angular

I'm toying around with Angular 2 RC5 and have run into the following problem:

> "Error: Type WelcomeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: WelcomeModule and AppModule!

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { WelcomeModule } from './welcome/welcome.module';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { 
    routing, 
    appRoutingProviders 
} from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
  BrowserModule, 
  RouterModule, 
  WelcomeModule,
  routing
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { 
    Routes,
    RouterModule 
} from '@angular/router';

import { welcomeRoutes } from './welcome/welcome.routing';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
     ...welcomeRoutes
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**welcome.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ]
})
export class WelcomeModule { }
```

**welcome.routing.ts**

```
import { 
    Routes,
    RouterModule 
} from '@angular/router';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';

export const welcomeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];

export const welcomeRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const welcomeRouting = RouterModule.forChild(welcomeRoutes);
```

I can see what Angular is complaining about, `welcomeRoutes` requires `WelcomeComponent` from `WelcomeModule` to be defined, `appRoutes` references `welcomeRoutes` and `routing` is imported in `AppModule` which has `WelcomeModule`imported, but how am I supposed to build a routes graph spanning multiple modules then?

The only solution that I can see is to remove

```
import { WelcomeModule } from './welcome/welcome.module'
```

but that kind of would defy the whole purpose of having modules in the first place, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load the same route configuration for root and child but they have to be different route configurations. For a full example see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: That shines some light on the issue, but I still have trouble with nested modules, will make that a separate question.

Comment: @ThorstenWestheider do you have a link for that separate question? I landed on this post with a similar issue :).

Answer (score 6):

This problem was simply fixed for me by moving the declaration to a commonly used module and including it in the export so it could be used from other modules. Simplified code example below.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [
        WelcomeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        WelcomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first time I added `WelcomeComponent` to `AppModule` was by writing

```
import { WelcomeModule } from './welcome/welcome.module';
```

because `WelcomeComponent` is inside `declarations` of that module.

I then added `WelcomeComponent` a second time by writing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
     ...welcomeRoutes
];
```

as `WelcomeComponent` is the component to navigate to and it appears it is added to `AppModule` implicitly.

I solved the problem by changing `app.routing.ts` to

```
import { 
    Routes,
    RouterModule 
} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Declaring `welcomeRouting` as `RouterModule.forChild` makes `welcome` a child route automatically.