# Type Y is part of the declarations of 2 modules - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to include a shared component "SimpleRadialChartComponent" in two separate modules in my angular 2 application. When I pass this component in declarations area in each module, I took this error:

Type SimpleRadialChartComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules

How can declare a shared component in two different modules?

Comment: Can you enlighten us with some code?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38966202/23118.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good pracitice is creating "shared" module for components, model objects, etc using in two or more modules.

All the guidelines and good practices you will find in [official documentation](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#01-01).

---

Detailed description of your problem, you can find [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10646):

> If you want to use a component across multiple modules, you'll need to
>   create a "shared" module and add that component the shared module's
>   exports. Then you add that shared module into your other modules
>   imports.